# How to open /dev/graphics/fb0 in kernel space?

Tags: graphics, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, framebuffer

I want to open `/dev/graphics/fb0` from kernel space and write to it to display a test pattern. Is there any way I can do that?

There is one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909849/writing-to-framebuffer-directly-on-android) related to this. But, in the answer, it's done from user space, which I don't want.

Comment: What output do you get on the command, fb-test -f 0 ?